# Python/kivy: initialising kivy properties

Tags: python, kivy, declaration, kivy-language

I am trying to initialize three numeric properties to hold the year, month and date in a calendar application. I've replicated parts of the code below.

```
from datetime import date
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen

class CalendarScreen(Screen):
    year = NumericProperty()
    month = NumericProperty()
    day = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.year, self.month, self.day = map(int, str(date.today()).split("-"))
```

The issue is that the the **init** method executes before the class level properties get declared. As a result the initialized values get overwritten. I've also tried using separate variables, but then get conversion errors. When trying to use class attributes, initialized values got reset to 0 in other methods. I haven't found anything relevant in the documentation and was wondering if there is a more elegant way to initialize Properties in kivy from function calls.

Many thanks!

Here is an executable example:

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.screenmanager import Screen
from kivy.properties import NumericProperty
from datetime import date


class CalendarScreen(Screen):
    year = NumericProperty()
    month = NumericProperty()
    day = NumericProperty()

    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(CalendarScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)
        self.year, self.month, self.day = map(int, str(date.today()).split("-"))
        self.weekday = ((date.weekday(date.today()) - self.day % 7 + 1) % 7)
        self.day = 1

    def button_filler(self, buttonno):
        if self.day <= 30:
            if self.weekday == buttonno[-1]:
                self.day += 1
                self.weekday = (self.weekday + 1) % 7
                print(self.day, self.weekday)
                return self.day - 1
            else:
                return ""
        else:
            return ""


class DemonstrationApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return CalendarScreen()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    DemonstrationApp().run()
```

and the kv file:

```
#:kivy 1.10.1

<CalendarButton@Button>:
    text_size: (self.width -5, self.height -5)
    halign: 'right'
    valign: 'top'
    text: "text"

<CalendarScreen>:
    year: self.year
    month: self.month
    day: self.day
    weekday: self.weekday

    GridLayout:
        BoxLayout:
            CalendarButton:
                id: btn10
                text: root.button_filler("btn10")
```

The issue is that whilst the values for year, month and day are set correctly, when the filler method is called, all appear to have been reset to 0.

Comment: I think I would expect this to work. Can you give a full runnable example?

Comment: Yes of course,I am running this on Ubuntu so you might have to change the require.

Comment: Any news on this?